# Publish r shiny application in intranet

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a Rstudio/Shiny App and post it in our intranet so that everyone else in our office could see it. I am a windows person, and the instructions online about how to setup a shiny server within Linux environment is a bit difficult for me. Is there an easy way that I can could accomplish this goal without messing up with Linux. Even if I have to do so, is there an easy way to just have my webpage available to people within our company, not everyone on the internet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use shinyapps.io and add a password authentication by using, for example, `shinymanager`  [Link](https://github.com/datastorm-open/shinymanager) here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a computer that's always on, you can run R on it and run the command `shiny::runApp(host="0.0.0.0", port="xxxx")"`. You can experiment a bit with the port in `xxxx`.

You will have to know the computer's ip-address. You can then direct your colleagues to `http://<ip-address>:<xxxx>`, where you replace `<ip-address>` and `<xxxx>` with the respective ip-address and port. You might have to unblock the port in Windows Firewall.

If you do not have a computer available that is always turned on, you can actually install R onto a network drive, install required packages on the network drive, and then have users run R from the network drive and run the app themeselves.

Comment: Hi, but won't it make my data public by using this technique. If anyone has my ip address and the port number, any one can access the application.

Comment: Not if you put it on your intranet. Your computer's ip-address is local to the network, not the internet.

Comment: Can we deploy more than one application at a time using this?

Comment: Yes. If you host the application on your own windows computer, you simply launch separate R processes, each with a separate port. If you are using the "self-deployment" approach (which is sketchy at best - but if it works!), you can use the same base-installation, but let users load different scripts.

Comment: I will still recommend that you look into e.g. ShinyServer or ShinyProxy for self-hosting solutions. The suggestions I have given are not sustainable solutions, but will display the possibilities Shiny for you and your organisation. Next step will be to build sustainable solutions with a proper server.